# Centered body with max width in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, width, bootstrap-4

I would my Bootstrap 4 webpage to have max width of 960px, including the top navbar. I have tried to enclose everything within the body with a div with max-width set. However, then this "body div" is left aligned. I would like the "body div" to be in the middle with whitespace around when the view port width is larger than 960px.

How would this be best achieved?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Max body width</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id= "body-div">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick = "toggle();">Toggle max-width</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         function toggle(){
             var div = $('#body-div');
             if(div.css('max-width') !== "960px"){
                 div.css('max-width', '960px');
             }
             else{
                div.css('max-width', '');
             }
         }
    </script>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tristique, dui vitae pharetra sollicitudin, felis metus dignissim sapien, at sodales libero massa condimentum dui. Maecenas sem diam, porttitor eget lacus at, vulputate facilisis leo. Nulla ut nisi sem. Nunc sapien neque, maximus fermentum mi ut, dapibus fermentum nunc. Phasellus dignissim laoreet dictum. </p><p>Sed egestas sem ut viverra dignissim. Sed blandit rhoncus turpis, ac feugiat tortor venenatis id. Ut ac fermentum enim. Integer vitae malesuada sem, nec ultrices mi. Fusce mattis ante vel lacinia convallis. Integer posuere nisi sit amet augue ultrices, quis elementum ante consequat. Sed et ornare lectus. Phasellus rutrum luctus ipsum non vestibulum. Etiam efficitur nulla at erat blandit, sit amet tristique ante gravida. Proin tortor purus, eleifend vel metus hendrerit, tincidunt tristique sapien. Donec lacinia aliquam lacus, in efficitur velit facilisis ac.</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsbin.com/towapid/1/edit?output

Comment: You know that the Bootstrap default for larger screens is wider than 960px, right? You still want to limit the max width to 960px?

Comment: And what's with the JavaScript in the code? You don't need any of that to make it work.

Comment: Good question. Yes, I want the page to look identical on large screens and extra large screens.

Comment: @WebDevBooster: Re javascript: just for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it in Bootstrap 4:

Note: this solution doesn't use your body-div or any other hacks because there's no need for any hacks. This can all be done with native Bootstrap classes alone.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
   <div class="container">
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
       <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
           <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
       </button>

       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
           <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
               <li class="nav-item active">
                   <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
               </li>
               <li class="nav-item">
                   <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
               </li>
               <li class="nav-item">
                   <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
               </li>
           </ul>
       </div>
   </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
   <div class="row no-gutters">
       <div class="col col-lg-10 offset-lg-1">
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tristique, dui vitae pharetra sollicitudin, felis metus dignissim sapien, at sodales libero massa condimentum dui. Maecenas sem diam, porttitor eget lacus at, vulputate facilisis leo. Nulla ut nisi sem. Nunc sapien neque, maximus fermentum mi ut, dapibus fermentum nunc. Phasellus dignissim laoreet dictum. </p>
           <p>Sed egestas sem ut viverra dignissim. Sed blandit rhoncus turpis, ac feugiat tortor venenatis id. Ut ac fermentum enim. Integer vitae malesuada sem, nec ultrices mi. Fusce mattis ante vel lacinia convallis. Integer posuere nisi sit amet augue ultrices, quis elementum ante consequat. Sed et ornare lectus. Phasellus rutrum luctus ipsum non vestibulum. Etiam efficitur nulla at erat blandit, sit amet tristique ante gravida. Proin tortor purus, eleifend vel metus hendrerit, tincidunt tristique sapien. Donec lacinia aliquam lacus, in efficitur velit facilisis ac.</p>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Here's an alternative version (you might like this better):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
   <div class="container">
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
       <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
           <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
       </button>

       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
           <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
               <li class="nav-item active">
                   <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
               </li>
               <li class="nav-item">
                   <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
               </li>
               <li class="nav-item">
                   <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
               </li>
           </ul>
       </div>
   </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col mx-5">
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tristique, dui vitae pharetra sollicitudin, felis metus dignissim sapien, at sodales libero massa condimentum dui. Maecenas sem diam, porttitor eget lacus at, vulputate facilisis leo. Nulla ut nisi sem. Nunc sapien neque, maximus fermentum mi ut, dapibus fermentum nunc. Phasellus dignissim laoreet dictum. </p>
           <p>Sed egestas sem ut viverra dignissim. Sed blandit rhoncus turpis, ac feugiat tortor venenatis id. Ut ac fermentum enim. Integer vitae malesuada sem, nec ultrices mi. Fusce mattis ante vel lacinia convallis. Integer posuere nisi sit amet augue ultrices, quis elementum ante consequat. Sed et ornare lectus. Phasellus rutrum luctus ipsum non vestibulum. Etiam efficitur nulla at erat blandit, sit amet tristique ante gravida. Proin tortor purus, eleifend vel metus hendrerit, tincidunt tristique sapien. Donec lacinia aliquam lacus, in efficitur velit facilisis ac.</p>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>



    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Cool. What does the "mx-5" class in the second example do?

Comment: It's just a horizontal margin that pushes the sides in a bit. (since you didn't want the normal, default width)

Answer (score 3):

To center align a div like that, all you need to do is add a `margin:auto;` to the `#body-div`. The margin is calculated based on the width of the div.

So in your css, you just need to add this:

```
#body-div{
   margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! If I wanted a similar appearance to Stack overflow where the contents of the top menu (nav-bar in my case) has a maximum width but the border of the top menu stretches out to the edges of the browser - how would that be done?

Comment: Bootstrap also has the class `m-auto` for this.

Comment: @Klooven Take your header out of the body div, nest the header in another div, apply the border styling to the outer div while putting the max width and margin auto on the inner div.